# Python Não consigo importar o ReCaptchaField

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, recaptcha

tem um projeto que me foi enviado no qual irei trabalhar em cima dele.
Criei um environment para subir o projeto e no projeto tinha o requeriments onde rodei ele.
Porem ao executar o comando `python manager.py runserver` ele esta me dando o erro:

> Exception Value: cannot import name ReCaptchaField

O erro completo segue a baixo, como podem ver ele esta no INSTALLED_APPS

> Django Version: 1.8.15 
>   Python Version: 2.7.12 
>   Installed Applications: 
>   ('django.contrib.admin', 
>    'django.contrib.auth', 
>    'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
>    'django.contrib.sessions', 
>    'django.contrib.messages', 
>    'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>    'django.contrib.sites', 
>    'django.contrib.flatpages', 
>    'sorl.thumbnail', 
>    'grappelli.dashboard', 
>    'grappelli', 
>    'captcha', 
>    'axes', 
>    'rest_framework', 
>    'rest_framework.authtoken', 
>    'auditoria') 
>   Installed Middleware: 
>   ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware', 
>    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', 
>    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>    'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware', 
>    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware', 
>    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware', 
>    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware', 
>    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware', 
>    'axes.middleware.FailedLoginMiddleware', 
>    'auditoria.CurrentRequestUserMiddleware') 
>   File "/srv/www/vhosts/projeto/projeto/interfacepub/forms.py" in   
>     from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField  
>    
>   Exception Type: ImportError at /Admin  
>   Exception Value: cannot import name ReCaptchaField

Já claro procurei por esse erro na internet e todas as soluções que estão lá não me resolveram. Fiz a instalação via `pip` tentei colocar nas variáveis de ambiente e continuou dando erro:

> export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH/srv/www/vhosts/project/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Quem souber alguma maneira de resolver. Obrigado.

Comment: Provavelmente os requirements estão sendo instalados no ambiente Python errado. Você sabe qual o caminho para o Python usado para executar a aplicação? Tem certeza que é o mesmo que da usa linha de comando (`which python` dirá este último)? Está usando virtualenv?

Comment: Então eu entrei na pasta do projeto 
`/srv/www/vhosts/project/`
Dei o comando para iniciar a environment
`source ./project/bin/activate`
Depois dei o 
`which python`
`/srv/www/vhosts/project/project/bin/python`
acredito então que esta correto.

Comment: E foi com esse Python que você instalou os requirements?